# Create X.509 Authorization Certificate

Tags: authorization, x509certificate, digital-certificate

Can we programmatically create X.509 Certificate which contains arbitrary attributes e.g. Age, Gender, Designation etc.

I need to create Authorization Certificate, which client application will present to server application before executing the required function.

I am using Java and C#, so any solution/suggestion is good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [site](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)  for a start.

Create keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias youralias -keyalg RSA -keypass yourpassword123 -keystore yourKeystoreRSAMD5 -storepass store123 -sigalg MD5WITHRSA -validity 9999 -dname "CN=Common Name, OU=XYZ, O=Your company name, L=Your Town, S=Region, C=Countryname"
```

Export cert file in PEM format

```
keytool -export -alias youralias -file rsamd5YourKey.cer -keystore yourKeystoreRSAMD5 -storepass store123
```

Comment: thanks ... I got it. I am wondering how can I create the physical file (*.cert) to store in the client application.

Comment: If you're using java have a look at the keytool.exe application in the java bin folder. I have updated the original answer with sample commands.